# How to modify the PATH environment from an Azure Pipelines step using git-bash as the bash script on Windows?

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, git-bash

I am trying to make a subset of my bash Azure Pipelines steps to work on a Windows machine where git-bash is installed.

My problem is with the download tool step which I have implemented like this so far:

```
parameters:
  - name: tool
  - name: url
    type: object
    default:
      Linux:
      Windows_NT:
  - name: version
    default: latest

steps:
  - bash: |
      PS4='##[command]  ' ; set -euox pipefail

      tool=${{ parameters.tool }}
      version=${{ parameters.version }}

      if type $tool 2> /dev/null; then exit; fi

      if [[ $AGENT_OS == Windows_NT ]]; then
        WINDOWS_PATH="$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY\\$tool\\$version;$WINDOWS_PATH"
        AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY=${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY//\\//}
        url=${{ parameters.url.Windows_NT }}
      else
        url=${{ parameters.url.Linux }}
      fi

      ...

      set +x
      if [[ $AGENT_OS == Windows_NT ]]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WINDOWS_PATH]$WINDOWS_PATH"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$WINDOWS_PATH"
      else
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/$tool/$version:$PATH"
      fi
    displayName: Install ${{ parameters.tool }}
```

The problem is `$PATH` is mangled by git-bash and is not suitable as a Windows PATH, but when altering the `PATH` I must use the windows `PATH`, not the mangled one.

My solution is drag around `PATH` (which is mangled by git-bash) and a copy `WINDOWS_PATH` which for git-bash just some variable, which it does not mangle.

This produces quite an ugly code.

Is there a better solution?